# execute custom callbacks immediately after redux store update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga, redux-thunk

How do I execute custom callback that is passed into an action through react comp, immediately after redux store update.
The idea is say, I trigger an action from react, which will make network request via thunk and dispatches the action with data. This will lead to reducer updating the store. Now, immediately after this I want to redirect to a different page (`history.push()`) which is a callback.

Using `saga` middleware it is much easier, but how to implement similar functly using `thunk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your callback defined in your component the redirect to different page to the thunk and call that after store update is complete. Like this:

```
function someThunkAction(callback) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Update store logic...
    // After update
    callback();
  };
}
```